# Variable does not exist: Quantity

Tags: apex, unit-test, compile-error

> Variable does not exist: Quantity

Although it does exist as I added a value to it and it worked fine

this is the code

```
@isTest
public class AssetTriggerTest2 {

    @isTest static void test(){

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'farah test';
        insert acc;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'tests';
        opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
        opp.StageName ='Demo';
        opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
        opp.Type='New';
        opp.Demo_Date__c = Date.today();
        opp.New_Vehicle_Feed_Provider__c ='AutoFunds';
        insert opp;

        Product2 p1 = new Product2();
        p1.Family = '360 Suite';
        p1.IsActive = true;
        p1.Name ='360 Suite';    
        insert p1;

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        PricebookEntry pb1 = new PricebookEntry();
        pb1.Product2Id =p1.Id;
        pb1.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
        pb1.UnitPrice = 100.00;
        pb1.IsActive = true;
        insert pb1;


        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                                                OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                                                Quantity = 5,
                                                PricebookEntryId = pb1.Id,
                                                TotalPrice = Quantity * pb1.UnitPrice
                                                                                    );
        insert oli;


        opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
        update opp;



    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference another field in your `Field=value` assignment pairs. If you want to reference a value relative to another field, use a constant to store the initial value.

```
Integer QUANTITY_VALUE = 5;
OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
    Quantity = QUANTITY_VALUE,
    TotalPrice = QUANTITY_VALUE * pb1.UnitPrice
    // other fields
);
```

Or if you really want to reference the value of another field, you can break it out into a separate assignment, outside your `SObject` constructor.

```
OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
    Quantity = 5
    // other fields
);
oli.TotalPrice = oli.Quantity * pb1.UnitPrice;
```